# How do i make 'index.php' higher priority than 'index.html' with a Shell script

Tags: php, shell, unix

I'm automating a server setup and to install PHP I need to add `index.php` to `/etc/apache2/mods-enabled/dir.conf`.

The target content of the file looks like this:

```
<IfModule mod_dir.c>

          DirectoryIndex index.html index.cgi index.pl index.php index.xhtml index.htm

</IfModule>
```

I need to add `index.php` before `index.html`.

It should end up looking like this

```
<IfModule mod_dir.c>

          DirectoryIndex index.php index.html index.cgi index.pl index.xhtml index.htm

</IfModule>
```

How do I do this with a shell script?

Comment: Your directive already contains an `index.php`, do you actually need to add it twice?

Comment: I would recommend to put all params necessary into a repository / database and generate an `.htacces` instead of fiddling around in central config (which needs at least a reload of apache processes once changed)

Comment: @AxelAmthor I'm simply following this tutorial to install PHP on Ubuntu 12.04 => https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-linux-apache-mysql-php-lamp-stack-on-ubuntu

Comment: But that's for manual installation. I didn't get why you want to do this by a script?

Comment: Thanks for clearing that up Niels.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All you're doing is making index.php higher priority than index.html. It's an odd thing to need to do, and probably better done in .htaccess or something. However, if you really want to make the change in the config file directly you can use `sed`. In this case something like the following:

```
cd /etc/apache2/mods-enabled
sed -e 's/\s*DirectoryIndex.*$/\tDirectoryIndex index\.php <...> index\.htm/' \
    dir.conf > dir.conf.tmp && mv dir.conf.tmp dir.conf
```

You need to be sure that 'DirectoryIndex' only appears once though, and fill in <...> with the rest of the line (escaping dots: 'index.pl' -> 'index\.pl').

Answer (score 1):

Or you can also try the next,

- will do the replace only inside of the `<IfModule mod_dir.c>` block
- will add `index.php` to the begining of the line if not exists
- reorder the line if in the `index.php` already exists in the line
- don't change the other entries  order
- create an backup file .bak

```
conf="./dir.conf"

err() { echo "$@" >&2; return 1; }
line=$(sed '/<IfModule *mod_dir.c>/,/<\/IfModule>/!d' "$conf" | grep -o -m1 'DirectoryIndex.*')
[[ ! -z "$line" ]] || err "No mod_dir.c" || exit 1
repl=$(echo $(echo DirectoryIndex;echo index.php; tr ' ' '\n' <<<"$line" | grep -Ev 'index\.php|DirectoryIndex'))
sed -i'.bak' "/<IfModule *mod_dir.c>/,/<\/IfModule>/s/$line/$repl/" "$conf"
```